# Export iCloud items from Keychain to CSV

Tags: icloud, keychain, password, macos

I want to export all my accounts login/password from Keychain. But you have many categories like : login, iCloud, System... in the Keychain menu. In fact I want to export them to 1Password, so I follow [this overflow answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/137250/export-keychains).

But in `~/Library/Keychains/` I have only the `login.keychain` and not the hopefully `iCloud.keychain`...

I have 422 accounts in the iCloud category and only 5 on the login category...

So my question is, how can I save/export this iCloud category

[image]

into a keychain or .csv file ?

EDIT :

I have already a login.keychain file. But I don't know how I can make an iCloud.keychain file.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A late reply, as I found this post while searching for something related.

You have to create a new keychain, and copy your iCloud keychain items to the new local keychain.  Then you can use the security tool to dump them.

Since this is 1Password-related question, for others in the future, you can use MrC's conversion utility to directly convert the keychain dump into a 1Password consumable 1PIF file.  It is much better than CSV importing.

https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/30286/mrcs-convert-to-1password-utility/p1

Comment: seems to be the fastest way — create a new keychain, then copy the keys into it, then close the keychain. Move it to the new mac, then open with Keychain Access (or double click on the file), then copy the keys into the master keychain. Works beautifully.

Comment: as of Catalina, there seems to be no way to copy iCloud keychain items.  Attempting to copy them in the Keychain app results in an ambiguous error message.  And the CLI security tool doesn't show awareness of the iCloud keychain at all.

Comment: @Chris The said applescript works on Safari 12. With some changes, it can work on Safari 13 also  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359377/mojave-icloud-keychain-copy-paste-error/409708#409708

Comment: Within the *Keychain Access* app using *Ventura*, the 'ambiguous error message' appears to be: "An error has occurred. Unable to add an item to the current keychain: One or more parameters passed to a function were invalid."

Answer (score 3):

It's easy. Open Safari, go to **Preferences**, and then **Passwords**. Click on the three dots at the bottom, you will see **Import Passwords** and **Export Passwords**. This will export as `.csv`. Also, the passwords are not masked or Encrypted.  [image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm on 10.13.6. The MrC's tool, while great for the local keychain, it didn't work for me for iCloud items. Nor did the [script to retrieve passwords from Safari](https://1password.community/discussion/comment/455305/#Comment_455305).

[moxiefrog](https://1password.community/profile/discussions/moxiefrog) at [1Password forums posted a solution](https://1password.community/discussion/comment/455708/#Comment_455708) based on Automator that worked for me. Essentially, this script mimics a user doing copy-paste from each item to a text file.

Below is **moxiefrog**'s code which I have adapted for my macOS version. You may have to adjust the number of tabs (see `keystroke tab` below), also taking into consideration what fields you would like to copy. As it is, running the script will produce a text file with the following format:

```
username,website,password
```

## Steps

1. Open *TextEdit* and create a new document
2. Open *Keychain*
3. Click on the *iCloud* keychain and sort it in the order that will be copied to the text document
4. Locate the line `keystroke "password"` and insert your password (including the quotes)
5. Run it once and check if it copied successfully, otherwise you may have to adjust the `delay`'s and/or order and number of tabs.
6. If everything went fine, increase the `repeat` value in the first line. Doing batches of 50 is recommended.
7. Save the text file file as `.csv`.

## Script

```
repeat 1 times
    delay 0.2
    tell application "Keychain Access"
        activate
        
        tell application "System Events"
            --- Open a keychain item
            delay 0.2
            keystroke return
            --- Press Tab x3
            delay 0.1
            keystroke tab
            delay 0.1
            keystroke tab
            delay 0.1
            keystroke tab
            
            -- Press ⌘C to copy item title
            delay 0.2
            keystroke "c" using command down
        end tell
    end tell
    
    --Switch to TextEdit
    delay 0.2
    tell application "TextEdit"
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            -- Press ⌘V
            delay 0.2
            keystroke "v" using command down
            
            -- Type a comma
            delay 0.2
            keystroke ","
            
        end tell
    end tell
    
    --Switch to Keychain
    tell application "Keychain Access"
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            -- Press Tab x2 
            delay 0.1
            keystroke tab
            
            -- Press ⌘C
            delay 0.2
            keystroke "c" using command down
        end tell
    end tell
    
    --Switch to TextEdit
    delay 0.2
    tell application "TextEdit"
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            -- Press ⌘V
            delay 0.2
            keystroke "v" using command down
            
            -- Type ','
            delay 0.2
            keystroke ","
        end tell
    end tell
    
    --Switch to Keychain
    tell application "Keychain Access"
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            -- Click the “Show password:” checkbox.
            delay 0.2
            keystroke "c" using {shift down, command down}
            
            -- Type password - update to yours
            delay 0.5
            keystroke "password"
            delay 0.2
            keystroke return
            
            -- Close keychain item window
            delay 0.3
            keystroke "w" using command down
            
            -- Go to next keychain item
            delay 0.2
            key code 125
        end tell
    end tell
    
    --Switch to TextEdit
    delay 0.2
    tell application "TextEdit"
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            -- Press ⌘V
            delay 0.2
            keystroke "v" using command down
            
            -- Press Return
            delay 0.2
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
end run
```

## Disclaimer

> Use at your own risk. If you know how to use AppleScript and Automator, then you might be just dangerous enough to screw things up. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

1Password 4 for Mac now supports importing of CSV format files

iCloud (Apple) Keychain items can be exported to a CSV file using script:
[Convert OS X Keychain exported entries into logins for 1Password import](https://gist.github.com/rwest/1583781)

Another option is to save new items to 1Password after they've been filled with login details from Safari's AutoFill (which can remain enabled as long as you'd like).

please refer this [discussions](https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/comment/137713/#Comment_137713). You'll probably find particularly helpful posts #20 from AgileBits and #39 from AgileBits.

Comment: This github script take the login.keychain but I want the iCloud category. So my question is, how can I export the iCloud category into .keychain file for using the git script above or how can I export the iCloud category directly in CSV.

Comment: (If you have multiple keychains you should repeat this whole process once from step 2 onwards for
 each one. You will have to change 'login.keychain' to 'foo.keychain' or somesuch.)

Comment: So, that's why I am asking for "how to make the iCloud.keychain" file... You can see my edit above.