# How can I list all my passwords stored in Keychain Access?

Tags: macos, security, password, keychain

I am trying to use the 'security find-internet-password' command to show my passwords.
I want to write a script to loop through my keychain and list all of my passwords. 
I have read the man page for security and tried the examples but cannot get it to return any of my passwords.

Here is the command from the man page:

```
find-internet-password [-h] [-a account] [-s server] [options...] [-g] [keychain...]
            -a account      Match account string
            -c creator      Match creator (four-character code)
            -C type         Match type (four-character code)
            -d securityDomain
                            Match securityDomain string
            -D kind         Match kind string
            -j comment      Match comment string
            -l label        Match label string
            -p path         Match path string
            -P port         Match port number
            -r protocol     Match protocol (four-character code)
            -s server       Match server string
            -t authenticationType
                            Match authenticationType (four-character code)
            -g              Display the password for the item found
            -w              Display the password(only) for the item found
```

I have tried several syntaxes for the command including leaving the keychain value blank. in the below examples admin is a account name for one of my internet accounts.
I would prefer to be able to get all of the passwords at once but when I dump-keychain it gives an unreadable mess of text with lots of tags that I cannot parse. Is there any

```
$ security find-internet-password -a admin -g 
$ security find-internet-password -a admin -g login
$ security fine-internet-password -a admin -g user
$ security find-internet-password -a admin -g /Users/Chilly/Library/Keychains/user
```

I would prefer to be able to get all of the passwords at once but when I dump-keychain it gives an unreadable mess of text with lots of tags that I cannot parse. Is there any documentation on the web for the format of that dump file or how to parse it. Suggestions I have seen say to just 'grep' the file but I need documentation to know what to look for.
(and to read a manual on grep and awk and sed but those are widely available:-)

Answer (score 4):

This will dump your login passwords:

```
sudo security dump-keychain -d login.keychain > keychain.txt
```

And this is a script that can convert it to a human readable format: https://gist.github.com/rwest/1583781

NB: The Ruby script worked for me only after I removed the line containing `.gsub!('htps', 'https');`.

And, optionally, here is an applescript which will autoclick for you the OS security confirmation dialog: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/137336/66812.

Comment: Check [this comment](https://gist.github.com/rwest/1583781#gistcomment-1633085) for a ruby script working without removing lines!

Comment: worth noting this is only login passwords. most of the interesting passwords are in iCloud passwords...

Comment: This command resulted in an endless stream of master password requests

Comment: @DISC-O: see the last part of the answer..

Comment: @ ccpizza- thanks but isn't there an easier way? I figured out what I need here :https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290896/search-icloud-keychain-for-all-accounts-that-use-a-specific-password/469337#469337. I dont know why it got downvoted, worked great for me.