# Search iCloud keychain for all accounts that use a specific password

Tags: icloud, security, password, keychain

I used one of those services that scans the internet for compromised passwords, and some passwords I recognized came up, and some that I didn't.   In any case, I want to search my keychain for all account credentials that are using that password so that I can go and change them, however the manual method of going through each one is too slow / painful.

Is there an easy way to retrieve all accounts from Apple's iCloud Keychain that use a specific password (assuming you have regular access to the keychain) -- I am aware of solutions for local keychains, but all my passwords happen to be locked in the cloud and the local keychain solution doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 1):

iCloud Keychain has notifications for duplicate passwords. If you identity (or create) an entry with the password you are concerned about, you will receive a list of duplicates.

Navigate to your passwords, either on macOS via Safari Settings or System Settings, or on iOS in the Settings app. Click the "Security Recommendations" section at the top of the screen, above the list of passwords. It may not appear if there are no duplicates. It will show a list of entries with reused passwords.

Search the list for the entry you know contains the password you're looking for. If you can't find it on the list, then it may not be used anywhere else. Once you find it, click it and read the note. It will indicate which other website it's used on. Go to that website, change your password, and repeat until no duplicates are found.

[image: iOS Passwords List]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I understand this does not answer your question directly, but on Mac, you can see all the passwords that have potentially leaked and fix them.

Comment: Please [edit] and explain how you get to the UI shown in your screenshot - what is the screenshot of?

Comment: @Greenonline There aren't really any steps, it's just the password screen

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue. I subscribe to multiple credit/identity protection services and regularly get alerted that my password has been found in the dark net. Unfortunately most services only provide the login/email, which I use in hundreds of sites, and not the password. The only service that provides a partial password is Chase.

But I digress. Having an email (login), a compromised password in hand (or a part of it) but not knowing where it is used, you can  now search your key chain on Mac by doing the following:
In Safari go to Preferences -> Passwords. At the bottom of the list of sites and passwords is a little button, the right most, with a little circle and dots in it, click that and you can export all login info to a clear CSV file. I also store my passwords in the cloud and it seems to export everything.
Just make sure to delete the csv when done!